# Spring Transactions - UnexpectedRollbackException in live, TransactionSystemException in tests

Tags: spring, transactions

We identified a transaction nesting issues after seeing UnexpectedRollbackExceptions in a production logs. This was because we handle specific database errors fairly close to the @Transactional persistence code, but further up at the service level was another @Transactional annotation that errored because the transaction was set to rollback only (as explained here: http://codetreasury.com/2014/01/25/springs-transactional-important-points/)

Our tests were initially too low level, so I added some further up the stack to confirm our fix, however the transaction exception thrown is different:

In live we see: UnexpectedRollbackException
In JUnit/Spring integration tests we see: TransactionSystemException

I'm concerned our tests are inconsistent with live code - can you explain why the exceptions are different?

Comment: If you have Transactional annotation at service, then why at persistence layer? It is difficult to say why it is failing in JUnit test, but I think the problem is same.

Comment: We removed the @Transactional at the service layer - layers are: (message) Gateway -> Service -> Processor (visitors) -> @Txn(Persistence). If a duplicate key exception is thrown in one of the 'Processors' then it is captured and some extra tasks are performed before returning.

Comment: The JUnit test isn't failing, its just throwing a different exception to production (the test confirms the duplicate key exception is handled)

Comment: I would suggest to do the exact opposite, remove annotation of Transactional from persistence code. It is unnecessary as the already existing transaction from Service layer will be propagated. What you described still seems like a JUnit problem, not a code problem.

Comment: Also, very difficult to say without seeing the code. Try this out, In the Test annotation, add the expected parameter and give the UnexpectedRollbackException.class. Try it out with that.